# Selective sorting

Tags: python, sorting, business-intelligence

I'm a Python newbie and I would like to implement a contingency table that deals with binary or categorical lists (that models the features of a dataset). For those who don't know, a contingency table is a matrix that in the generical element `m_ij` has a number that specifies how much times the element `i` of the first feature is in the same osservation of the element `j` of the second feature.
It's clear that every element (taken once) of each features should become a row or column header.
My problem is when I deal with binary feature. In this case, the contingency table must have as headers the couple (1,0) in this rigid sequence.

```
_|1|0|
1| | |
0| | |
```

While, with the code I've written this rigidity is not guaranteed: if binary feature has a 0 as first element, the relative header will not start with 1.

See my code:

```
def compute_contingency_table(first_f, second_f):
'''
This method compute contingency table of two features
:param first_f: first feature
:param second_f: second feature
:return: the contingency table
'''

first_values = get_values(first_f)
second_values = get_values(second_f)
contingency_table = np.zeros([len(first_values), len(second_values)])
corresponding_values = []

# for each value of the first feature
for h in range(len(first_values)):

    # find all the indeces in which it occurs
    f_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(first_f) if x == second_f[h]]

    # save the corresponding values in the second feature
    for ind in f_indices:
        corresponding_values.append(second_f[ind])

    # createing contingency_table
    # for each value in corresponding values of the second feature
    for val in corresponding_values:
        # take its index in the values list (i.e. the column of contingency table)
        k = second_values.index(val)

        # increment the value of the corresponding contingency table element
        contingency_table[h, k] += 1

    del corresponding_values[:]

return contingency_table
```

Use case:

```
first_f=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
second_f=[0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

Contingency table output by my code:

```
[[ 4.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
```

While it should be:

```
 [[ 0.  1.]
 [ 2.  4.]]
```

As you can see, this happens because the output table is of type

```
_|0|1|
0| | |
1| | |
```

It should work if it sorts headers in (1,0)-way with binary; no sort if they are caterogical. That is what I mean for selective sort.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using pandas?  This type of contingency table is a one-liner.

Comment: Yes, because I was trying to do it on my own, but, at this point, could you show me your one-liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done in this way:

```
def compute_contingency_table(first_f, second_f):
'''
This method compute contingency table of two features
:param first_f: first feature
:param second_f: second feature
:return: the contingency table
'''


first_values = get_values(first_f)
second_values = get_values(second_f)

if first_values == [0,1]:
    first_values = [1,0]
if second_values == [0,1]:
    second_values = [1,0]

contingency_table = np.zeros([len(first_values), len(second_values)])
corrisponding_values = []
for i in range(len(first_values)):

    f_indices = [k for k, x in enumerate(first_f) if x == first_values[i]]
    for ind in f_indices:
        corrisponding_values.append(second_f[ind])

    for s_val in corrisponding_values:
        k = second_values.index(s_val)
        contingency_table[i, k] += 1
    del corrisponding_values[:]

return contingency_table
```

Use case 1:

```
hair=['black', 'blonde', 'red', 'blonde', 'red', 'red', 'brown']
country = ['usa', 'china', 'usa', 'germany', 'germany','china', 'usa']
print(compute_contingency_table(hair,country))
```

OUTPUT

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

Use case 2:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
print(compute_contingency_table(a,b))
```

OUTPUT

```
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 2.  4.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're curious how the contingency table creation could be done in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['first'] = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
df['second'] = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
contingency_table = df.groupby(['first', 'second']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

or

```
contingency_table = pd.crosstab(df['first'], df['second'])
```

---

Regarding sorting, to swap the order in case of binary values doing the following in the `compute_contingency_table` should be sufficient.

```
first_values = list(set(first_f))
if len(first_values) == 2:
    first_values = sorted(first_values, reverse=True)
second_values = list(set(second_f))
if len(second_values) == 2:
    second_values = sorted(second_values, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see, the output has header in (0,1) way while I need (1,0)

Comment: I added a note how you could solve the sorting issue you had. Does that solve it for you?

Comment: Great work, but in your edit if I have features composed by two categorical attributes, the code reverses the normal order, while I don't want it. See my own answer: I've solved there. Really thank you, Martin